# After data model migrated, admin site was not synchronized

Tags: django

I defined data model in `models.py` and migrated them:

```
In [58]: ! python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'forums':
  forums/migrations/0002_test.py
    - Create model Test
In [60]: ! python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, forums, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying forums.0002_test... OK
```

`models.py`

```
class Block(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("block name", max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField("block description", max_length=100)
    admin = models.CharField("block admin", max_length=100)


class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("block name", max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField("block description", max_length=100)
    admin = models.CharField("block admin", max_length=100)
```

However, when I visited admin page, there's no data model there.

[image]

How to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your admin.py from within that app, you need to register the models.

```
from . import models

admin.site.register(models.Block)
admin.site.register(models.Test)
```